# React Native app with Mapbox Navigation Android SDK not getting GPS Location on Android 12

Tags: react-native, android-12, mapbox-navigation

I have built a navigation app using React Native 0.72 and Mapbox Navigation Android SDK 2.8.0.
The app starts with a react native page having a button to open a Mapbox navigation view. When I click the button, I would expect the map to track my current gps location.

The navigation works on Android 7. But when I am testing on an Android 12 device, the navigation view  gets stuck at google headquarter as its location. When I debugged it, the map view can receive location update but the latitude and longitude remains as google headquarter.

Would really appreciate it if anyone has any insights.